# how to read line by line string in a text file?

Tags: c++

this code will only read and calculate the first input in the input.txt file and ignore the rest of the inputs in the input file.I have been trying to solve it so that it can read all the rest of the inputs and calculate them.
this is my code i think there is something wrong with it.

i have tried several looping methods

```
int main()
{
  string inputLine;

  ifstream file ("input.txt");// input file to be read
  ofstream file1;
  file1.open("output.txt");


  freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);// store all the output to this file

  while (std::getline (file, inputLine)) // read the strings in the input file
  {
    if( strncmp( "----", inputLine.c_str(), 4 ) == 0 )
      continue;

    //calculating binary and hexadecimal values
    char *opr = "^+-/%*=,()";
    std::string::iterator end_pos = std::remove(inputLine.begin(), 
    inputLine.end(), ' ');
    inputLine.erase(end_pos, inputLine.end());
    string str=inputLine;
    string str2="";
    int length=str.length();
    char t[length];
    str.copy(t, length);
    t[length] = '\0';
    char* tok;
    char *cop=new char [length];
    str.copy(cop,length);
    char *w = strtok_fixed( t, opr );

    while (w!=NULL)
    {
      string w2=w;
      std::stringstream tr;
      tr << w2;
      w2.clear();
      tr >> w2;
      int x=w2.length();
      int y=x-3;

      string check= w2.substr(0,3);
      string check1=w2.substr(0,x);

      if(check.find("0x") != std::string::npos)
      {
        unsigned int x= strtol(w2.c_str(), NULL, 0);
        std::ostringstream s;
        s << x;
        const std::string ii(s.str());
        str2=str2+ ii;
      }
      else if (check1.find("b")!=std::string::npos)
      {
        w2.pop_back();
        long bin=std::strtol(w2.c_str(),0,2);
        std::ostringstream s2;
        s2<<bin;
        const std::string t2(s2.str());
        //inputLine.replace(inputLine.find(w2),(w2.length()+1),t2);
        str2=str2+t2;
      }
      else
      {
        str2=str2+w2;
      }
      char a =cop[w-t+strlen(w)];
      string s1="";
      s1=s1+a;
      std::stringstream tr1;
      tr1 << s1;
      s1.clear();
      tr1 >> s1;

      str2=str2+s1;
      w = strtok_fixed (NULL, opr);
    }

    //str2 should be taken to the parser for final evaluations
    Parser p(str2);
    double value = p.Evaluate ();
    std::cout<<"----------------------"<<endl;
    std::cout << "Result = " << value << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"----------------------"<<endl;

    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.   Why are you using `strncmp` with `std::string`?  Try `std::string::find`.

Comment: Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.  Indicate which statement is causing the issue.  Also state the expected input and expected output.

Comment: why _freopen_ rather than to use the output stream ? `char *opr = "^+-/%*=,()";` must be `const char *opr = "^+-/%*=,()";` `string s1="";` can be just `string s1;` ...

Comment: I encourage you to compile with the options `-pedantic -Wall` and to remove the problems signaled by the compiler

Answer (score 2):

The problem is at the end

```
return 0;
 }

 }
```

should be

```
 }
return 0;

 }
```

You are returning from inside your while loop instead of after your while loop finishes.

You should spend the time to indent your code correctly. It will help you spot this kind of error. You should also learn to break up your code into smaller functions. Again this will help you understand your own code a bit better.